# Syntax error near an equal sign

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why it does this. Here's the code.

```
ac1 = input('1=Jab, 2=Punch, 3=Kick, or 4=Taunt?: ')
if ac1 = 1:
    print('You jab at Apollo Creed. He dodges it.')
    print('Apollo Creed continues to taunt.')
```

I'm making a Text based game based on the Rocky movies. :D the 1=jab and stuff means One equals Jab (if you type 1, you jab.)

Answer (score 1):

Single `=` sign is assignment. Equality is double `=`:

```
if ac1 == 1:
```

Comment: @Lava `input` returns a string, so you'll need to quote the 1

Comment: @Lava if this answer is correct, please mark it as such, for future programmers.

Comment: @cricket_007 The OP is using Python 3.x, so input returns an int.

Comment: @Selcuk - I don't think so. Then again, I do most stuff in Python2... http://stackoverflow.com/a/20449433/2308683

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single equals sign, this is used to ***set*** variables.

Use double equals `==` to check if a variable is equal to something.

```
ac1 = input('1=Jab, 2=Punch, 3=Kick, or 4=Taunt?: ')
if ac1 == 1:
    print('You jab at Apollo Creed. He dodges it.')
    print('Apollo Creed continues to taunt.')
```